# Laurent Series about $z=0$ of $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^3 - iz}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So far:
$$ \frac{1}{z^3 - iz} = \frac{1}{z(z^2 - i)} = \frac{i}{z} - \frac{iz}{z^2 - i}
 $$

Now I see that:
$$ \frac{-iz}{z^2 - i} = z\left(\frac{i}{i - z^2}\right), $$
and this is where I get stuck. I know the standard result for
$$\frac{1}{1-z^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\inf}z^{2n}, $$ 
but I don't know if/how I can apply that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\frac{i}{i-z^2}=\frac ii\cdot\frac{1}{1-z^2/i}=1\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-iz^2)^n$$

Answer (score 2):

Another way to reach the same result as Arthur (though it looks slightly different). Lengthier but gives some insights that otherwise could be lost:

Since $\;\omega:=\frac1{\sqrt2}(1+i)=\sqrt i\;$ and since $\;|z|<1\implies \left|\frac z\omega\right|<1\;$ , we get:
$$\frac i{i-z^2}=\frac i{(\omega-z)(\omega+z)}=\frac i{2w}\left(\frac1{\omega-z}+\frac1{\omega+z}\right)=\frac12\left(\frac1{1-\frac z\omega}+\frac1{1+\frac z\omega}\right)=$$

$$=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{z^k+(-1)^kz^k}{\omega^k}\right)=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(1+(-1)^k\right)\frac{z^k}{\omega^k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2k}}{\omega^{2k}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2k}}{i^k}$$